# Cannot find freeglut.dll, as suggested in tutorials

Tags: c++, file, freeglut

I am trying to get into c++/freeglut programming, yet I feel like an absolute monkey. The tutorials refer to a Freeglut.dll file that is in the bin folder. But as I unpacked the newest version of the freeglut binary, I was unable to find the bin folder or the .dll-file.

I was tying to install freeglut in my code::blocks.

I don't know exactly what to do.
(Don't make fun of me if my problem is stupid, I am borderline new to programing)

sorry for my bad english, it is not my first language.

I tried to follow many tutorials, but all of them refer to a file I was unable to find.

Comment: The easy way is using a package manager. A good one for MinGW (the compiler you're using) is [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2). Use it to install to install both GCC and FreeGlut. Uninstall your version of GCC to avoid conflicts. Configure CB to use MSYS2's compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably downloaded the source code. You would still have to compile this source code to get the desired dll file. It could be that your system already has a precompiled package of [freeglut](https://freeglut.sourceforge.net/#:%7E:text=Pre%2DCompiled%20Packages)

On some systems such as Debian and Ubuntu, it is as simple as running:

```
apt install freeglut3-dev
```

There are also binaries for [Windows MSVC and MinGW](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/), which do indeed contain a DLL file in the bin folder.

Otherwise you can build from source:

> Also if you can't find a suitable package for your system, don't panic; building freeglut from source is very easy, just follow the instructions in README.cmake in the freeglut source.

Comment: I downloaded the newest stable realease,(3.4.0) from the sourceforge mirror.
As for as I know that is the binary and not the sourcecode, yet I may be wrong about this seing, as I am quite new to this.

Comment: That would be the source code: "The freeglut project does not distribute pre-compiled or otherwise system-specific packages for freeglut."

Comment: @cum-bria The "Stable Releases" are source code. You need to keep reading until the next section; "Pre-Compiled Packages".